# Tomcat stuck thread detection in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat

Tomcat document provided configuration to handle stuck thread by enabling
**threshold** and **interruptThreadThreshold** subsequently.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve

I have enabled it in spring boot 2.x.x for embedded tomcat using bean based configuration and achieved it. It is able to kill thread if it is exceeding threshold.

I am looking for what is cons for enabling it. As of now i did not get any docs about best practices.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You should really ask yourself why do you need to configure this setting. The main reason usually is to prevent resource exhaustion in a production environment. But this is a mitigation, not a solution. Every time a thread is killed it means some task has not been completed, and there is potential for data corruption. The best practice should be to analyze **why** a thread is taken too much time and fix it whenever possible.